# How to create a user authenticated by public/private key in Postgresql and not with password

Tags: postgresql

How Do I create a user authenticated by "public/private key" in Postgresql and not with a password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html) that describes that in detail:

- set up SSL on the server with the [`ssl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-SSL), [`ssl_cert_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-SSL-CERT-FILE) and [`ssl_key_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-SSL-KEY-FILE) parameters
- configure a CA certificate on the server with the [`ssl_ca_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-SSL-CA-FILE) parameter
- add a `pg_hba.conf` entry starting with `hostssl` with the authentication method [`cert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-cert.html)
- on the client, use the [`sslcert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLCERT) and [`sslkey`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLKEY) connection parameters to specify the certificate and private key to use

Comment: I do not think this answer is correct. Even the latest Postgres provides certificate authentication: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/auth-methods.html. Certificate auth requires SSL certificates, and requires the cn (Common Name) attribute of the certificate  to match database user name. Proper Keypair auth, like what's used in linux-ssh or with Snowflake (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/key-pair-auth) does not seem to be supported by Postgres.

Comment: @VinayakThatte That looks right. But why does that make my answer wrong?